# fill background color only 50% of it total width

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible in CSS to fill background color only 50% of its total width?

I am trying make a progress bar where I need to fill background color based on the `"%"` of progress.

Please provide pointers.

Comment: another Approach: define a border on the left or right edge of the DIV and set the border width to the width of the div. color border and background differently. generalisations to different completion rates are left to the Reader ... ;-)

Comment: Embed a table with 1 Row and 2 cells, Setting the cellsto different Background Colors and allotting a dynamic percentage f the constant available with to the cells.

Comment: why negative vote....great power great responsibility

Answer (score 61):

There are multiple different ways to achieve this.

### Pseudo element approach:

```
<div class="progress"></div>
```

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9px8p/)

```
.progress {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}
.progress:after {
    content: '\A';
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    left: 0; 
    width: 50%; /* Specify the width.. */
}
```

### Linear-gradients approach:

The advantage to this approach is that you can specify multiple different colors.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/whumgbs5/)

```
.progress {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black 50%, white 50%);
}
```

---

### Animation without JS/JQUERY

Either of these approaches can be animated with pure CSS:

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pNL8Q/)

```
.progress:after {
    /* other styling .. */
    width: 50%; /* End width.. */
    -webkit-animation: filler 2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: filler 2s ease-in-out;
    animation: filler 2s ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes filler {
    0% {
        width: 0;
    }
}
```

### Transition approach

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9jncx/)

```
.progress:after {
    /* other styling.. */
    width: 0;
    transition: all 2s;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s;
}
.progress:hover:after {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: thanks I was wondering if it was possible with only 1 div using background colore

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mjEDY/1/ I did this fiddle just for fun, using yours as a base

Comment: Shouldn't "left" be "to right" for the gradient approach? Or are single-word values acceptable too?

Comment: @Pyromonk - Good catch, updated - thanks! For some reason `left` seemed to be valid when using the `-webkit` vendor prefix over 7 years ago.

Comment: @JoshCrozier, it appears to still work (at least with `-webkit`), but [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient()) only lists values starting with "to". Thank you for getting back to this so quickly and for a very helpful response!

Comment: @JoshCrozier any idea why the linear-gradient might not be working on safari when used on a table row (tr)? it repeats the linear gradient if using the same (or another % figure) on the second given hex colour

Answer (score 11):

Yes, by using gradients' stops, it's possible even with one div;

HTML

```
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
div {

  width:400px;
  height:400px;


  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #00ff00 50%, #ff0000 50%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #00ff00 50%, #ff0000 50%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #00ff00 50%, #ff0000 50%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #00ff00 50%, #ff0000 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(left, #00ff00 50%, #ff0000 50%);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use an absolute `div` with 100% height and change it's width using javascript.

It looks pretty cool:
Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uenzQ/)

Answer (score 4):

I did a progressbar animation using Josh C's answer: http://jsfiddle.net/mjEDY/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="prog">
    <div id="filler" class="filler"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.prog {
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.filler {
    width:0%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:black;
}
```

JS:

```
var stepSize = 50;
setTimeout((function() {
    var filler = document.getElementById("filler"),
        percentage = 0;
    return function progress() {
        filler.style.width = percentage + "%";
        percentage +=1;
        if (percentage <= 100) {
            setTimeout(progress, stepSize);
        }
    }

}()), stepSize);
```

It uses a few advanced javascript tricks (closures and setTimeouts for animation), but you get the idea.. With a little twiddling you can use it to create a progress bar based on whatever you want and no need for js plugins either :)

Comment: Is it possible to use it on borders, without the inner div i mean?

Comment: @ErtürkÖztürk Not sure I understand what you want, but you could style the inner div to any style you want, same with the outer div. If you want it to not have filler just don't set any background-color and instead you could have just border, for example.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use background properties of CSS3 for a progress bar, using a wrapper div.

```js
var stepSize = 50;
setTimeout((function() {
    var wrapper = document.getElementById("imageWrapper"),
        image = document.getElementById("preview"),
        percentage = 0;
    return function progress() {
        wrapper.style.backgroundSize = percentage + "% 100%";
        image.innerHTML = percentage + "%";
        percentage +=1;
        if(percentage <= 100){
            setTimeout(progress, stepSize);
            if(percentage == 100) image.style.opacity = 1;
        }
    }
    
}()), stepSize);
```

```css
div#imageWrapper{
 width:100px;
 height:120px;
 background: url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAAAAAP///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==') no-repeat;
 background-size:0% 100%;
 background-position:0 100px;
}
div#preview{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
    background: url('http://sugarbird.skyauction.com/content/qart_140775b.jpg');
 background-size:cover;
 opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="imageWrapper">
    <div id="preview"></div>
</div>
```