# Angular create progress filling upload button

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I am looking to write my own upload button that while the file is uploading the background will fill in green. Some things I am not aware of how to do, get the current width of the button inside of the component without directly using document.getElement. I need to do the calculations on the current progress number to set the fills. Lastly, I need to data-bind to the css properties to easily update the UI.

Something like this has the input of `Progress: number` which I will update from another view as the file is reading. I don't understand how to use `Progress` variable to achieve something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647184/fill-background-color-only-50-of-it-total-width).

My code has a pretty clear definition of the steps I need to achieve, the biggest step I don't know how to do is to get ahold of the `<button>` inside the component without using the `document.getElementById()`.

My basic view:

```
<button [disabled]="Disabled" (click)="Clicked()" type="{{Type}}" class="btn btn-md spacing FakeClickable btn-info"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload fa-lg"></i> {{Content}}</button>
<form>
    <input id="FileUpload-{{Content}}" [hidden]="true" type="file" name="file" (change)="FileReady($event)" />
</form>
```

The OnChange event for this component:
***UPDATE - Following the guide linked here but nothing seems to happen. I am updating the correct values but nothing happens. The only thing that happens is the background color does change but not fill.***

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges)
  { 
    if (changes["Progress"] && changes["Progress"].currentValue != undefined)
    { 
      if (this.Progress != 100)
      {
        var thingy = this.fileBtn.nativeElement as HTMLButtonElement;
        // Remove the btn-info class from the button
        thingy.classList.remove('btn-info');
        // Get the current width of the button
        var curWidth = thingy.clientWidth;
        // Set the buttons background color to green
        //thingy.classList.add('btn-success');
        thingy.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        // Set the background fill percentage to Progress
        thingy.style.backgroundSize = `${this.Progress}% 100%`;
        thingy.style.backgroundPosition = `0 ${curWidth}px`;
      } else
      { 
        var thingy = this.fileBtn.nativeElement as HTMLButtonElement;
        thingy.classList.remove("btn-info", "btn-success");
        thingy.classList.add("btn-info");
        thingy.style.backgroundColor = "";
        thingy.style.backgroundSize = `${this.Progress}% 100%`;
        thingy.style.backgroundPosition = `0 ${curWidth}px`;
      }  
    }  
  }
```

Comment: Use [progressbar by ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/progressbar)

Comment: I don't want to add anymore dependencies I just want to use my own code.

Comment: i would suggest a directive for this.

Comment: additionally look into https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2 for manipulating the DOM

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the button inside your component class code, then you're looking for `ViewChild`. Your code will look like this:

```
<button [disabled]="Disabled" #uploadButton (click)="Clicked()" type="{{Type}}" class="btn btn-md spacing FakeClickable btn-info"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload fa-lg"></i> {{Content}}</button>
```

This is your template, we create a local variable named `uploadButton` and then will access it from our Component Class using `ViewChild` decorator:

```
import { ViewChild, ElementRef  } from '@angular/core';
// then:
@ViewChild('uploadButton') uploadButton: ElementRef;
ngOnChanges() {
   // this is how you access your button:
   this.uploadButton.nativeElement // do anything with it, this is just a usual HTML element reference
}
```

Comment: I have just started down that path, I will post any updates if I hit any snags.

Comment: Wouldn't suggest this approach in this case. You'll end up having the logic for your button in every component where you need this behaviour. A directive which has a `@Input` for your current progress would suit this usecase very well.