# HTML css partial fill background

Tags: html, css

I have a `nav li` that on hover the background goes white. However I also want part of the background (a portion of the left of the element) to be grey on the hover. So about 25 percent of the element needs to be grey while the other 75 needs to be white all on a hover.

I have so far:

```
nav li:hover{
background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [Gradients](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp);

something like:

```css
nav li:hover{
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(left, grey 25%, white 75%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(left, grey 25%, white 75%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(left, grey 25%, white 75%);
    background:-linear-gradient(left, grey 25%, white 75%);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Navigation Link 1</li>
    <li>Navigation Link 2</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Another answer that might help you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647184/fill-background-color-only-50-of-it-total-width)

Comment: is this the only code in the css necessary ? cus it didnt work for me

Comment: @Derek try it now, it depends on what browser you are using

Answer (score 5):

I would use straight `linear-gradient`

```
nav li:hover{
background: linear-gradient(to right, black 25%,black 25%,#000000 25%,white 25%,white 100%);
}
```

See the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y3crk9uv/)