# How to provide background color to x% width of Ag Grid Cell?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I want to apply background color to Ag Grid Cell based upon dynamic width. Column is basically showing progress of task e.g 1/20(5% green) , 2/4(50% green) so i need to show background color like progress bar.

Comment: Please see this thread for CSS solution via sudo class.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647184/fill-background-color-only-50-of-it-total-width

Comment: If i want to use linear gradient method provided in above mentioned link, do i need to provide both colors, is it possible to specify only one color for x% width and keep (100-x)% as it is?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do that using by using `rgba()` function to set the `background-color`. Here is my implementation

```
function ProgressCellRenderer(props) {
  const progress = props.data.completedTasks / props.data.totalTasks;
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          width: progress * 100 + "%",
          height: "100%",
          backgroundColor: `rgba(130,210,73,${progress})`
        }}
      />
      <div style={{ position: "absolute" }}>{(progress * 100).toFixed(2)}%</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Usage

```
<AgGridReact
  columnDefs={[
  {
    headerName: "Completed Tasks",
    field: "completedTasks",
  },
  {
    headerName: "Total Tasks",
    field: "totalTasks",
  },
  {
    headerName: "Progress",
    cellRenderer: "ProgressCellRenderer"
  },
  ,...]}
  frameworkComponents={{
    ProgressCellRenderer
  }}
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit cold-voice-lnyge]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use cellRender to return the element:

```
cellRenderer: params => return 
    `<div class="flex progress-bar__container" ng-if="isProgress()">
        <div class="flex--1" ng-class="{'progress-bar': ii <= getStage() }" ngFor="ii in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]"></div>
    </div>`
```

Above code is sudo code of Angular, you can change it to react.